# Overriden onPause onStop onDestroy finish do not work in Cocos2dxActivity after game closing in cpp code by CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end()

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

Overriden onPause onStop onDestroy finish do not work in Cocos2dxActivity (my activity extends it) after game closing in cpp code by CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end()

If I go to home screen or other app onPause onStop are called.

But I need know when game finished in java code.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this situation I called my Cocos2dxActivity via startActivityForResult and I get callback onActivityResult. But due to described situation I cannot use setResult Cocos2dxActivity in right way (in onPause).